# How to create conda env with yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, dependencies, conda

I want to use some AI model, main folder has cog.yaml file in it:

```
build:
  gpu: true
  python_version: "3.8"
  system_packages:
    - "libgl1-mesa-glx"
    - "libglib2.0-0"
  python_packages:
    - "torchvision==0.9.0"
    - "torch==1.8.0"
    - "numpy==1.19.4"
    - "opencv-python==4.4.0.46"
    - "tqdm==4.62.2"
    - "Pillow==8.3.2"
    - "timm==0.4.12"
    - "ipython==7.19.0"
predict: "predict.py:Predictor"
```

How to create conda env using this yaml file?

I tried `conda env create -f cog.yml` and got error

Comment: What did the error _say?_ Error messages are there for a reason. They give helpful information. Please always include error messages verbatim when asking questions here (and read them yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Your file with the YAML document has the name `cog.yaml`. So that file has follows the recommendation (from September 2006) to give such files the extension `.yaml`.

But you invoke Conda on a file named `cog.yml`. YML is a completely different [format](https://fdik.org/yml/), based on XML and at least as old as YAML. You should never use the `.yml` extension, if your file contains one or more YAML documents, as this (as you prove yourself) leads to confusion.

What should work better (unless your `cog.yaml` contains configuration errors):

```
conda env create -f cog.yaml
```